# How to get the next activity based on the current instance id in Tridion2013

Tags: 2013, core-service, workflow

How can I get the next Workflow activity after I have gotten the processdefinition for the current instance id using the Core Service?

Below is the code which I have already:

```
ActivityInstanceData currentActivity = 
    (ActivityInstanceData)client.Read("tcm:222-122108-131104", null);
ActivityDefinitionData activitydefinition = 
    (ActivityDefinitionData)client.Read(currentActivity.ActivityDefinition.IdRef, null);

ProcessDefinitionData processdefinition = 
    (ProcessDefinitionData)client.Read(activitydefinition.ProcessDefinition.IdRef, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways for this, but it depends on what exactly you intend to do. If you finish the current activity with `CoreServiceClient.FinishActivity(ActivityInstance.Id, finishData, null);` this method will return an Activity Instance Data object that represents the next Activity Instance, or null if this is the last activity.